# Minecraft command block specifiers "[Data value] [Data tag]"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When using command blocks some commands ask for *[Data value]* and *[Data tag]*. I know what *Data values* are. But what are *Data tags*? How do translate the Data specifications that I need into "command block language"? And is there a rubric or reference page where I can find all of them so I won't have to bug you all with every specific thing I'm trying to do.

Comment: Well, a link is kind of necessary. I don't expect someone to just post every block ID and Data tag. And an in depth explanation is nice too.

Comment: Well, we wouldn't need to post every block ID (those weren't mentioned in the question). And as for data tags, that's not really just a list of values... it's more complicated...

Comment: You can see my [in-dev Google site](https://sites.google.com/site/mechaofminecraft/) on this sort of stuff.

Comment: "Data value" is right there in the title. So just in case someone clicked on it for [Data Values] (http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Data_value)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the basics of commands in Minecraft Java Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354614/what-are-the-basics-of-commands-in-minecraft-java-edition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data tags give you access to the (formerly) internal data for each entity or block. You can pretty much do anything (that is possible in the game engine) by modifying the data tags. For example, if you want a white horse:

```
/summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Variant:0}
```

If you want the horse to be tame and have a saddle:

```
/summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Variant:0,Tame:1,Saddle:true}
```

If you want to give the player a named shovel with Fortune X enchantment:

```
/give @p iron_pickaxe 1 0 {ench:[{id:35,lvl:10}],display:{Name:Lucky}}
```

The list of all possible tags is here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format.

---

The format is the following:

`DataTag` is `{` `NamedTag` `,` `NamedTag`,... `}`
`NamedTag` is `TagName` `:` `TagValue`
`TagName` is the tag name as seen in the above link (case sensitive)
`TagValue` is number or string or `DataTag` or `ValueList`
`ValueList` is `[` `TagValue` `,` `TagValue` ,...`]`

---

Using this 'grammar' we can break down the example `{ench:[{id:35,lvl:10}],display:{Name:Lucky}}` into its parts:
It is a `DataTag` that has two `NamedTag`-s: `ench:[{id:35,lvl:10}]` and `display:{Name:Lucky}`

The first `NamedTag`'s name is `ench` and its value is `[{id:35,lvl:10}]`. This value is a list with one item (we have one enchantment). The item is `{id:35,lvl:10}` and it is itself a `DataTag`. It has its own two `NamedTag`-s: `id:35` and `lvl:10` which show the enchantment id is 35 - Fortune and enchantment level is 10. If we want to add another enchantment to the shovel, we need to build a `DataTag` for it: e.g. for knockback `{id:19,lvl:5}`. Then we need to put the second enchantment in the list: `[{id:35,lvl:10},{id:19,lvl:5}]`

The second `NamedTag` of the root tag has name `display` and value `{Name:Lucky}`. This value is itself a `DataTag` that contains only one `NamedTag` - `Name:Lucky`. This `NamedTag` has name `Name` and value `Lucky`.

Comment: Mention something about "NamedTag:{}" and "NamedTag:[{},{}]" or something, and I'll love this answer. :)

Comment: @JamesOfDaPeach well, if you follow the 'grammar' I gave, deciphering combinations comes naturally. Nevertheless I have included a verbose example of breaking an expression down to its parts. It is really easier if you view the data tag as a tree with values (like folders and flies. The tree is converted to text using the above rules or 'grammar'.