# How do I send all players back to lobby

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

Basically, I'm trying to make a hunger games world in minecraft but I'm not sure how I can send all players back to spawn when the player wins.

Comment: Well if it's on the same server then a tp all command should work.

Comment: yea but i want to make it to tp everyone when theres only 1 person left

Answer (score 2):

First, have a look at [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/354615/229868) to learn more about commands. Your problem is that you need to `tp` all players to a location when there's one player left in the arena. So the steps you need to accomplish are:

1. Count the players
2. Store the amount of players
3. When that number is 1 (there is one player left in the arena) teleport all players to some location.

1. To do this, first set up a [scoreboard](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard) to count the players in the arena:
   `scoreboard objectives add numPlayers dummy`.
2. Then, at the center of the arena run `execute store result score number numPlayers run execute if entity @a[distance=..x]` every tick, where number is a fakeplayer and x is the distance from the center of the arena to the edges. This will constantly store the amount of players in the arena to the scoreboard.**
3. Now, if there is a 1 stored in the scoreboard (indicating one player left), you need to `tp` the players, so run `execute if score number numPlayers matches 1 run tp @a x y z`. This will teleport all players to the coordinates `x`, `y`, and `z` if there is one player left in the arena. Remember that `number` is a fake player we created to store the value, and their value is in the objective `numPlayers`.

**The way the storing works is that the `execute store result` command basically takes a value produced by the command after the `run` keyword and puts it in the latter half of the `execute store result` command, which in this case in `number`'s score in the objective `numPlayers`. The part after the `run`, `execute if entity @a[distance=..x]`, returns the amount of players because the `if entity` subcommand has two functions: running some command after the `if` if the condition is true, or returning the amount of entities that passed the test to what is before the preceding `run` keyword if there is no `run` keyword coming afterwards.