# Showing an item name on top of the hotbar without an item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to display a name on top of the hotbar in a specific empty slot, is this possible with commands?

Comment: Hi Nythcom, in general we like questions to show that the poster has put some effort into it. For general Minecraft commands questions, please read up on [this article](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354614/what-are-the-basics-of-commands-in-minecraft-java-edition), so you have a basic understanding of the subject, and can ask help for specific problems you have encountered.

Comment: im tired of people just downvoting and not answering a simple damn question like this im just asking a simple question and i need to "put more effort" into it?

Comment: Wonderful feedback, thanks! Well, I didn't downvote your question (also, how can you be tired of it when it's your first question?), but it is still how this platform works. Yes, "put effort into it": do you know what the limitations are of Minecraft commands, for example? Have you ever written a Minecraft command? Do you have a fundamental idea of the syntax?

Comment: alright, i found it thanks for the help it was title actionbar

Comment: @Nythcom As you found the answer, will you consider answering your question? That way other people with this problem will be able to come to this and see your solution. Thanks!

Comment: /title (player) actionbar {"text":"texthere"}

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer the question according to Nythcom's findings, you cannot manually put text where the names of items go when you select the item in your hotbar without a mod. Instead, use the [title command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/title) to put text in the actionbar, which is above the space where item names go. This is the same place the texts "Now playing..." from jukeboxes and "You cannot sleep now" go, so be sparing with it if you want to constantly put a message there.

```
/title <player> actionbar <raw json title>
```

The title command uses json format to determine what text you want to put there. A useful json text creator can be found [here](https://minecraftjson.com/).