# How to spawn different cat skins in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So i want to spawn different cat types in 1.14.4 using the /summon command..
How can i do that? in the new update there are much more cat skins and i would like to know how to summon different skins

Comment: Hi locipro, what have you tried already? Please check [this post on Arqade Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13507/what-to-do-before-asking-a-minecraft-commands-question), and the linked [article on commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354614/what-are-the-basics-of-commands-in-minecraft-java-edition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/summon cat ~ ~ ~ {Owner:locipro, CatType:3}
```

- Summon: Base command, spawn a mob.
- Cat: Mob type.
- ~ ~ ~: Position. ~ ~ ~ Is at your current location
- Owner: Specifies the mob's owner. Change `locipro` to your IGN.
- Cat type: Specifies the cat's skin

Cat Type ID system is found on minecraft.

> https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cat#Cat_type