# How can I make every zombie that I kill spawns me one diamond?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I played on a Minecraft map which had this minigame arena mode where you get diamonds for killing each kind of mob. With these diamonds you were able to buy better equipment until you killed all the mobs, and then you moved to the next level. Is there a command for that? I'm playing Minecraft 1.14.

Comment: Hi Tlots, what have you tried so far? Have you read [this post on Arqade Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13507/what-to-do-before-asking-a-minecraft-commands-question), and the linked [article on commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354614/what-are-the-basics-of-commands-in-minecraft-java-edition) already?

Comment: @galacticninja So you just took my edit and made it yours by just changing the last three words ? I think that's not a nice way to go

Comment: @G.Eiwell I reviewed (and approved) your suggested edit from [the review queue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/277902). Since I noticed that there are some issues with the question left unfixed, i.e. grammar, tags in question title, and unremoved salutations (see the meta posts on my edit notes) - I've edited them to fix the issues. This is one of the reasons why suggested edits are reviewed here: to have them checked for quality by reviewers.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is probably to set the loot table of every zombie to the loot table of diamond ore. You can do that by changing the `DeathLootTable` NBT data to the loot table that you want for that zombie. In this case that would be `"blocks/diamond_ore"`. The command to change the `DeathLootTable` for every zombie looks like this:

```
/execute as @e[type=minecraft:zombie] run data modify entity @s DeathLootTable set value "blocks/diamond_ore"
```

I recommend using a repeating command block. Doing so will make zombies drop some experience and a single diamond, even with a looting 3 sword, or a fortune 3 pick axe.

Comment: This will prevent regular drops like rotten flesh, this may be a positive, or negative side effect depending on your setup.

Comment: thx but if I want the diamonds to spawn somewhere else how can I do it?

Comment: @Tlots You could teleport the diamonds to where you want them. If teleporting them is too complicated, then this may not be the right solution for you. In that case it would be nice if you could give a bit more details on what exactly you want to do, like where to spawn the diamond, if zombies should drop something else, how many players are going to be in the map simultaneously, etc. If you feel like clarifying, then editing the question would be the best way to do it.

Comment: @Tlots Did teleporting the diamonds work for you, or do you need some more help?

Answer (score -2):

https://www.gamergeeks.nz/apps/minecraft/mob-generator
This website is great!
You put settings and customisation into it and then it gives you the command.
You can change the loot drops and the weapons and armour they hold. You can even change their health and name.
You can choose if you want a spawn egg, spawner, or a summon command.
I hope this helps!

Comment: The mob-generator does NOT have a way to change the loot... (not yet, supposed to come with newer versions)