# a minecraft command that tests if an item with an nbt tag is touching another item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Okay so I am trying to run a Minecraft command that tests if an item with an nbt tag is touching another item I have tried `/execute if entity @e[nbt={id:"minecraft:oak_planks"}] at @e[name=Glowstone] run time set day` I also tried `/execute if entity @e[nbt={Count:1b}] at @e[name=Glowstone] run time set day` but both do not work can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What do you mean with "touching"? Just being within a certain "`distance`"? I also don't really understand what those commands are meant to do. Please say what exactly you want and what happens instead.

Answer (score 0):

As Fabian Röling pointed out, your question isn't super clear, so this answer is based on my understanding of what you want:

If you want to test for an item entity 'touching' another item entity, you will need to test to see if the second one is within a certain radius of the first. To do this, use an `execute` command, executing `at` the position of the first item, and testing `if` there is the second entity nearby:

`execute as @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:oak_planks"}}] at @s if entity @e[type=item,distance=..<radius>,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:glowstone"}}] run ...`

Depending on how selective you want this command to be, you can choose your own `<radius>` value (make sure to leave the `..` right before `<radius>`, because it means 'less than or equal to' your radius; without it, the items will need to be exactly `<radius>` blocks apart for it to work). I found 0.5 to be a good radius value. You can add more filters to the selectors to adjust the command to your own preferences.

Additionally, I strongly recommend that you visit [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354614/what-are-the-basics-of-commands-in-minecraft-java-edition/354615#354615) page, which might help you learn more about how commands work.