# How do target selectors like @a and @p work in multiplayer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm building on a custom map that should work for both singleplayer and multiplayer.

I'm wondering how target selectors like `@a` and `@p` work in multiplayer. I know @a targets all players and @p targets the nearest player, but if i do:

```
/execute if entity @a[scores={kills=10..}] run say HI
```

...does it mean all players must have at least 10 kills or does it mean it checks all players and if one of them have 10 kills it says `HI`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the basics of commands in Minecraft Java Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354614/what-are-the-basics-of-commands-in-minecraft-java-edition)

Comment: `/execute if` on the Minecraft wiki: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/execute#Condition_subcommands TLDR: "at least one matching"

Comment: i still dont quite understand how it works i read the both texts you send but i didnt find the answer i wanted :(  anyways i forgot that i had two minecraft acounts so i can test it by my self thanks anyway