# Command Block Works then Stops Working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I play Minecraft Java Version 15.1.1 on a good-specs PC. I've been trying to figure out how to use command blocks but I don't know what keeps going wrong. I'm putting the Command Block well and good on the ground, I've used all kinds of levers, buttons, pressure plates to activate it.

I was trying to build a house and when I activate it, it just summons a column of sand blocks for about 5 secs then stops.

Comment: What is your command? Please edit this post to include your command.

Comment: Related: [What are the basics of commands in Minecraft Java Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/354614/4797)

Comment: This is the link; https://www.digminecraft.com/command_blocks/house.php I can't attach the code as it's too long.

Comment: That's the original code, but we'll need *your* code since that's probably where the cause of the problem lies.

Comment: I copied the same code and I also double checked it.

Comment: And I play Minecraft on TLauncher, but that won't be the cause of the problem because I've seen other youtubers use TLauncher and they can use command blocks well and good.

Comment: Even if this question was cleared up, it would still have to be closed for illegal software.

Answer (score 3):

The command that you linked is for a different version of Minecraft. Since commands can change between versions, that command will not work anymore. I would recommend finding a new command for your version. It is possible to reword the command, but it would require a lot of work.

Comment: try moving the  " ~ ~1 ~  " from the start of the command to the end. It may fix it.

Comment: To the end, do you mean after {id:falling_block,Block:redstone_block,Time:1} ?