# Can I clone an area to the coordinates of an armorstand in 1.18.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a map where, if you walk close to an armorstand, it disappears and clones something on the armorstand coordinates. I have already figured out a way for detecting if a player is near it and removing the armorstand. But is there also a command so I can clone on the cords the armorstand is standing?

I would like to use this feature with multiple armorstands on random locations so I cannot use specific coordinates.

**I am using version 1.18.2**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the basics of commands in Minecraft Java Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354614/what-are-the-basics-of-commands-in-minecraft-java-edition)

Comment: Apologies if I'm missing something obvious, but this seems to be just "how do I use relative coordinates", which is covered by the dupe target.