# What does "^ ^ ^" mean in a command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I watched a video about particle designing in Minecraft. And there they used `^ ^ ^` or `^[number] ^[number] ^[number]` instead of `~ ~ ~` or `~[number] ~[number] ~[number]`.
And now I wonder what this does.

(***Btw. I didn't understand the meaning of the text from: [What are the basics of commands in Minecraft Java Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354614/what-are-the-basics-of-commands-in-minecraft-java-edition). But here I  got a better explanation.***)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the basics of commands in Minecraft Java Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354614/what-are-the-basics-of-commands-in-minecraft-java-edition)

Comment: @pppery I would disagree because the linked question is broader than this question. For search result reasons, this question should stay open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Relative world coordinates

When specifying coordinates, each coordinate can alternatively be expressed as a relative world coordinate, written in tilde notation (~ΔX ~ΔY ~ΔZ).
A number following a tilde (~) describes an offset from execution position along one of the world axes, and a lone tilde assumes an offset of 0.

#### Local coordinates

The other way to describe positions is with local coordinates, written in caret notation (^ΔX<sub>local</sub> ^ΔY<sub>local</sub> ^ΔZ<sub>local</sub>).
Like relative coordinates, these describe positions relative to where a command is executed from, but with different directions. A number following a caret (^) is an offset within a moving, entity-centric frame: This coordinate system is centered at the executor's position, with +X<sub>local</sub> directed to its left, +Y<sub>local</sub> directed upward, and +Z<sub>local</sub> directed in the direction the sender faces.

Source, [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Coordinates).

---

To summarise, they do pretty much the same thing, only with a different orientation. `~~~` notation will always give the same coordinates (XZ world axis are fixed), `^^^` notation will change following your orientation (Z is where you are facing)